# qt installation and path in ubuntu

Tags: qt, installation-path

I have compiled qt in to /home/user/Software/qt-4.7.4 folder. Then Iset the path in .profile. I did the static built  before to /home/user/Software/qt-4.7.4-static-build. For some reason even after updating the PATH env variable it is not changed to the new path and keep giving me the old qmake version.

I tried source command but it does help, also when I try qmake -version it shows me the old path. if I try qmake in a qt project obviously it gives me

```
QMAKESPEC has not been set, so configuration cannot be deduced.
Error processing project file: /home/user/testUI.pro
```

can someone help me to get qt running. I am using ubuntu linux 10.04 and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alight After some head banging and consulting a few people I figured the solution my self. What I forget to mention was that I changed the name of the qt installation folder which is a BIG NO NO. Apparently qmake stores its path statically rather than using the path variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to update both the QT and QTMAKESPEC environment variables.

Comment: actully in qt installation guide it says that I just need to add the qtFolder/bin to the path environment variable. So this should be something else. and my issue mainly is that why that old path still exists over the one I ve already set.